# Dereferencing class with overloaded * operator

Tags: c++, operators, dereference

I'm trying to create a pointer to a class that have * operator overloaded, but it returns another value. 
Class code:

```
template<class T> class Node
{
public:
    T *pointer;

    T& operator*()
    {
        return *pointer;
    }
}
```

Then this code doesn't work, returning int instead of pointer:

```
Node<int>* examplePointer;      //this works
Node<int> example;            //creates an instance of Node<T> class
examplePointer = *example;           //this doesn't work
```

How can I make pointers with overloaded * operator?

Comment: You must have a T defined somewhere for the `Node<T>* examplePointer` to compile. Can you post a small example that compile with the suspiscious assignment commented ?

Comment: It's just a typo. As I said this is already solved by creating additional operator for pointers only.

Comment: What do you expect `examplePointer = *example` to do? `int x = *example` would work fine, as would `examplePointer = &example`.

Comment: I expected `examplePointer` to point to `Node<int>`

Comment: You return an int&, but expect it to be a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

This `Node<int>* example;` means that `example` is a pointer on a `Node<int>` (yes, I am captain Obvious :) ).

If you use it afterward with `*`, that does mean that you're just dereferencing the pointer to accessto the `Node<int>`. So, basically you have something like:

```
*example; // Just a pointer dereference expression type 
          // is something like Node<int>
**example; // something like:  example->operator*();
```

I do not really see what's your goal... Using a pointer to a container like this seems to creates a lot of indirection...

And more generally, you cannot overload an `operator*` outside a class definition, so you cannot define it for a pointer.

Comment: `Node<int>* example;` should create a pointer to `Node<T>` but instead it just uses the overloaded operator and makes `example` an `int`.

Comment: @chris710 `Node<int>* example` does declare a pointer to `Node<int>` and does not use the overloaded operator.. Here's an example : http://ideone.com/jZPtZM

Comment: OK, but then how to make a pointer in other situations like `exampleVector.push_back(*exampleNode);` ?

Comment: First of all, why do you want a pointer ? You're `Node<T>` is already a wrapper over a pointer. Second, I need some type signature to understand what you want. Is `exampleVector` a `std::vector<Node<T>>` ?

Comment: @chris710 sorry I forgot to mention your name in the previous comment to warn you.

Comment: Already edited for better clarity. I've created another operator to make a pointer to the Node class so the problem is somewhat solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try just `Node<int> example`. That gives you a Node, and `*example` will call your operator - so it behaves like a pointer.